# Compute the following by using Cauchy's Integral Theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{1+a^2\cos{t}}$$ where $ 0<a<1$. Could someone please help me? I know that I am supposed to do a change of variables, but at this point, I cannot even think straight.

Comment: This integral is so simple that it can be calculated with no complex functions. If you *want* to use the complex analysis, it is a good start to express $\cos t$ in terms of $z=e^{it}$ by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming no mistakes in the calculus) if $$f(t)dt = \frac{dt}{1 + a^2 cos(t)}$$
because of $cos(t) = \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2}$ you can write

$$f(t)dt = \frac{dt}{1 + a^2 \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2} } = 
\frac{2e^{it}dt}{2e^{it} + a^2 \left( e^{it} \right)^2 + a^2}$$

observe now that $e^{it}dt = -i d(e^{it})$ so if you pose $z(t) = e^{it}$ your integral will be evaluated along the curve $z(t)$, so basically you should have

$$\int_{\gamma^+} \frac{-2idz}{a^2 z^2 + 2z + a^2}$$

where $\gamma^+$ is the curve i described above.

For the rest, just study the roots of $p(z ; a) = a^2 z^2 + 2z + a^2$.

For the cauchy integral formula, decompose your function as

$$f(z) = \frac{A}{z - z_0} + \frac{B}{z - z_1}$$, 
$z_0,z_1$ are the roots of the denominator so basically

$$\int_{\gamma^+} \frac{-2idz}{a^2 z^2 + 2z + a^2} = \int_{\gamma^+} \left[ \frac{A}{z - z_0} + \frac{B}{z - z_1} \right] dz = \int_{\gamma^+} \frac{A}{z - z_0}dz + \int_{\gamma^+} \frac{B}{z - z_1}dz = I_0 + I_1$$.

Just to give a clue...

$$I_0 = \int_{\gamma^+} \frac{A}{z - z_0}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma^+} \frac{A}{z - z_0}dz = 2 \pi i \times \left[ \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma^+} \frac{A}{z - z_0}dz \right] = 2 \pi i I'_0$$

So basically, since the root $z_0$ will depends from $a$ you can study the integral $I'_0$ using the cauchy theorem.

I didn't make all the calculus... but i guess you were more interested in the idea. The same discussion is applied to $I_1$ of course.

Comment: Hey, our class has not covered the Residue Theorem. Is there anyway you could explain an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, yes just a sec.

Comment: Is that better?